# Laravel PHP: Validators Class inside 'Models' folder not found

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a folder named 'Validators' inside my 'Models' folder that contains the validation files for creating new records.  I have not had problems in the past putting this folder inside the 'Models' folder within my Laravel PHP project but for some odd reason when I try to create/store new records, I keep getting a Class 'Models\Validators\Stone' not found error.

**Controller:**

```
<?php

use Acme\repositories\StoneRepository;

use Acme\repositories\PhotoRepository;

use Models\Stone;

use Models\Stone_Photo;

/* 'Validators' folder inside 'Models' folder */

use Models\Validators as Validators;

     class StonesController extends BaseController {

     /*The stone model */

     protected $stone;

     /*The stone_photo model */

     protected $stone_photo;

     protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

     /* This is the function that is currently being called */

     public function store()
     {
       $input = \Input::all();

       /* This is where the error occurs on this line below */

       $validation = new Validators\Stone;

       /* Validation code here */       

     }    

 }
```

**Stone Validator (app\models\validators\stone.php):**

```
<?php namespace Models\Validators;

class Stone extends Validator {

/* The rules for validating the input */

public static $rules = array(
        'stone_name' => 'required',
        'stone_description' => 'max:255',
    );
}
```

I have tried running 'php artisan dump-autoload' but that still does not change anything.  This implementation has worked for me in the past but for some reason I keep getting this error and I don't know why.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think its the namespace issue. How did you configured your composer.json?

Comment: go to `vendor/composer`. open up the `autoload_classmap.php`. check the entries. if it is a namespace issue or any other typo/mistake.... you will know from those entries.

Comment: I think it was a case-sensitive issue since in one of my files, I had 'Models' and changed it to 'models' since that's how its defined in my local directory.  Thanks for the advice though guys!